# Experience of Python's "PEP-302 New Import Hooks"

Tags: python, specifications

I'm one of the developers of Ruby (CRuby).  We are working on Ruby 2.0 release (planned to release 2012/Feb).

Python has ["PEP302: New Import Hooks"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) (2003).  We are considering introducing a feature similar to PEP302 into Ruby 2.0 (CRuby 2.0) (*1).  Because of this background, I'm trying to gather opinions about Python's PEP 302.

*1: I want to make a proposal which can persuade Matz.  Currently, Ruby can load scripts from only the file system in a standard way.

If you have any experience or consideration about PEP 302, please share.

Exmaple:

1. It's a great spec. No need to change it.
2. It is almost good, but it has this problem...
3. If I could go back to 2003, then I would change the spec to...

I'm sorry if such a question is not suitable for StackOverflow.  I posted here because I'm not sure that I can ask this question at python-dev (of course, the list is not for ruby-development).

Thank you.

Comment: Programmers.se might be a better forum for this

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  The above question is enough for Programmers.se?

Comment: It should be pointed out that this did get asked and answered well at Programmers here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/154247/experience-of-pythons-pep-302-new-import-hooks